# Server side es6 transpiler for production

Tags: babeljs

In docs it's mentioned that babel-register and babel-node should not be used for production. The other alternative is to use babel-cli but it does not support relative paths for import. How to solve relative paths problem for babel-cli?

Comment: Generally you'd have one folder for ES6 and one for ES5, and you'd transpile the whole folder to the ES5 location, preserving the structure. Since the whole structure stays the same, the relative paths all work. Is that what you're having issues with?

Comment: @loganfsmyth That clears my my doubt partially. I have a webpack config which bundles the client/ , app/ folders and generates js files from from those and puts it in build/ folder. And the server/ code needs to be transpiled using babel-cli. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Usually you'd use folders, but you could also always compile with webpack and run that too I suppose.